# (GSON) Collection to Json String

Tags: java, collections, gson

I have the following row in my function:

```
Collection<Song> songs = a.getListOfSongs();
```

There are all required annotations in the Song class.
Need to return JSON String using GSON lib.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you `Song` class?

Comment: You know that you have to use GSON lib...Whats the problem then... too lazy to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `new Gson().toJson(songs)`. Although when you try to make Song bean from this json, you might have to face some casting issues like, int value would have converted to double, char to string...as GSON uses its intelligence to resolve such types

Answer (score 1):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(songs);
```